# How do I push an element into the array within an object in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have the following JavaScript object :

```js
[{
  Name: "Ishan",
  Code: 1,
  Is_Intern: "Yes",
  DateOfJoining: "01/02/2022",
  Skills: ["VB, DOT.NET, Angular"],
  Status: "Working"
}]
```

How can I add an item to the skills array in this object?

I didn't find any particular article regarding this.

Comment: you can add in `array` by `.push()`.

Comment: But How ? This is not a simple Array this is an array inside of a JavaScript object.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Please first ***>>>[Search for related topics on SO](https://www.google.com/search?q=javascript+add+to+nested+array+site%3Astackoverflow.com)<<<*** and  if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the [`[<>]`](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) snippet editor.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```js
var data = [{
  Name: "Ishan",
  Code: 1,
  Is_Intern: "Yes",
  DateOfJoining: "01/02/2022",
  Skills: ["VB, DOT.NET, Angular"],
  Status: "Working"
}]
data[0].Skills.push("New Skill");
console.log(data);
```